# r5rs eval not finding reference within its lexical scope

Tags: scope, scheme, eval, lexical-scope, r5rs

If `eval` with `(interaction-environment)` should have access to everything that's defined within the lexical scope of when it's called, then why am I getting this error when I try to run the below code?

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.3 [3m].
Language: R5RS; memory limit: 128 MB.
why does this work? object_function: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
```

Code:

```
(define (disp x)
  (display x))
(eval '(disp "why does this work?") (interaction-environment))

;The below doesn't work

((lambda ()
  (define (object_function x)
    (display x))
  (eval '(object_function "But not this?") (interaction-environment))))

(define (object)
  (define (object_function x)
    (display x))
  (eval '(object_function "And not this?") (interaction-environment)))
(object)
```

If I change it like so:

```
;The below does work

(define (object_function x)
  (display x))

((lambda ()
   (eval '(object_function "Why does it work now?") (interaction-environment))))

(define (object)
  (eval '(object_function "And now?") (interaction-environment)))
(object)
```

Output:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.3 [3m].
Language: R5RS; memory limit: 128 MB.
Why does it work now?And now?
```

With `eval` by itself it works just fine, but wrap it in a defined function or a lambda and it can't find the locally defined function that is within the same scope that the `eval` function is called.

I may be misunderstanding how `eval` or `interaction-environment` deal with lexical scope, but if someone can shed some light on this that would be helpful.

Comment: Your premise is false; `eval` shouldn't have access to that. `interaction-environment` is the interaction environment, not the local environment within your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `eval` evaluates data it does so at top level. The lexical depth from where you call `eval` is not leaked into the evaluation. The second argument only changes between the three different global environments you can access.

`define` inside a procedure or let is just a fancy `letrec` and thus a lexical binding. It will not be available from `eval`. Top level `define` makes a global binding and *it* will be available from `eval` iff `interaction-environment` is used.

Implementations don't have to implement `interaction-environment`, as it is optional. The required environments are `null-environment`, that only have special forms, and `scheme-report-environment`, which is the initial environment of the system.

`eval` is a powerful feature that is usually the wrong solution. Usually you are doing it wrong if you need to use `eval`.